# make && sudo make install doesn't work

Tags: git, macos, curl, makefile

I'm on OS X 10.6.6 trying to upgrade `git` and `curl`.

```
$ cd ~/Downloads/git-1.7.4.1
$ make && sudo make install
...
$ git --version
git version 1.7.3.2
```

It scrolls through and seems to work ok, but when I print the version of `git` (this happens with `curl` also) I still get the older version.  What do I need to do to fix this?

I was able to install the newest version of git through the .dmg file, but curl doesn't have one.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the output of the install. Where does it place the executable? If you have two versions of git in your `$PATH`, then it might be that it found the wrong one. And you are certain that no errors occurred?

Comment: It's installing in `/usr/local/bin/git` and `/usr/bin/git` comes first in the `$PATH`.

Comment: Well, not quite.  I don't want to change the order in `$PATH` as I'm unsure of the side effects elsewhere.  So, how could I tell `sudo make install` to install to `/usr/bin/git`?  Or should I remove the one in `/usr/bin/git` all together?

Comment: When you run `./configure` you can state where to install the files to. Like so: `./configure --prefix=/the/path`. This makes it install (when running `make install`) user binaries to `/the/path/bin`, system bins to `/the/path/sbin`, configuration files to `/the/path/etc`, and so on if applicable. But if you are not using `/usr/bin/git`, and you installed it yourself (or you don't want the version all together) then you might as well remove it.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  Just ran the `./configure --prefix=/usr` like you said so it overwrote the previous install.  But I think I'll just remove it completely or create a symlink  from `/usr/bin/git` -> `/usr/local/bin/git`

Comment: Bad idea.  Now you're confusing your package manager as to what's installed on your system. You should have prefixed /usr/local/bin to your $PATH instead.  That's what /usr/local is there for.